# Import error, can't find files in stackblitz

Tags: reactjs, frontend, dashboard

I'm using Stackblitz to practice ReactJS and it's coming up with an error when I attempt to import components in  App.js

Import error, can't find files:

**./pages/Register**
**./pages/Dashboard**
**./pages/Products**
**./../lib/constants**

```
import Layout from './components/shared/Layout';
import Register from './pages/Register';
import Dashboard from './pages/Dashboard';
import Products from './pages/Products';
```

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-xc8mtn?file=src%2FApp.js

Answer (score 0):

```
public
  |- index.html
src
  |__components
  |   ├── lib
  |   │   ├── constants. index.js
  |   │   └── helpers. index.js
  |   ├── pages
  |   │   ├── Dashbaord.js
  |   │   └── Products.js
  |   │   └── Register.js
  |   ├── shared
  |   │   ├── Header.js
  |   │   └── layout.js
  |   │   └── Sidebar.js
  |   ├── App.js
  |   ├── index.js
  |   ├── style.css
  |   └── index.html
```

here is your project tree structure, you should see the paths of folder structure and below you can see the define correct paths.

- src path should be `./`
- `components` -> `shared` -> `Layout`
- `components` -> `pages` -> `Register`

App.js

```
import Layout from './components/shared/Layout';
import Register from './components/pages/Register';
import Dashboard from './components/pages/Dashboard';
import Products from './components/pages/Products';
```

SideBar.js

```
import {
  DASHBOARD_SIDEBAR_LINKS,
  DASHBOARD_SIDEBAR_BOTTOM_LINKS,
} from '../lib/constants';
```

Dashboard.js

```
import DashboardStatsGrid from '../../components/DashboardStatsGrid';
import TransactionChart from '../../components/TransactionChart';
import RecentOrders from '../../components/RecentOrders';
import BuyerProfilePieChart from '../../components/BuyerProfilePieChart';
import PopularProducts from '../../components/PopularProducts';
```

and one more thing

When you are trying to use jsx in your javascript file, you should say to your compiler I am providing you a jsx in the file.

```
import React from 'react';
```